AppExchange Customers are unable to pay for my app because the "Manage Subscription" button does not appear
For a few months now, nobody has been able to see the "Manage Subscription" button for our app on Appexchange when navigating to "My Installs & Subscriptions". See the two images at the bottom.
I have tried a lot of things to fix this, none of which have worked.

Rolled the Stripe API key
Reconnected the CMA-Stripe connection and created a new stripe webhook (This is the part I was least confident about, because there was many Stripe webhook settings that Salesforce CMA gave no guidance on. However, it does seem to be receiving events, like price plan changes.)
Reconnected the Listing-Stripe connection after Salesforce support disconnected it so we could reconnect

Other Listing information...

The app's payment method is "After Installation"
Payment Management is "Appexchange Checkout"... aka CMA, not COA

Thank you! Louis
NORMAL APP

OUR APP


Under "Installed Packages," the "configure" button is also missing as shown here
https://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-invoicing-a-beginners-guide/

However, my user does have both "Download AppExchange Packages" and "Manage Billing"

Lastly, under installed packages, my org did not come with "Salesforce Billing" or "Salesforce CPQ"

Under "My Installs and Subscriptions", the app also stays under "Trial Subscriptions" even when it is marked active in the LMA.

When clicking download on the app, a "Confirm Installation Details" page comes up. This page has a "Duration" and "Number of Subscribers" column for the license that will be installed for the trial. Our app shows "Duration"  as "Does Not Expire" and "Number of Subscribers" as "Site-wide", even though the default license for the Package is 15 days and 5 licenses.
